# Unix/Linux - service unit file cannot recognize env variable set in /etc/environment

Tags: linux, bash, unix, environment-variables

I have an environment variable setup correctly in `/etc/environment`

I have ensured that it loads correctly via `/etc/profile` modification. and I can echo it to confirm.

but when I created the unit file for my service, it fails because the environment variable is missing. However, I can start the script on it's own normally.

here is my service unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Zookeeper unit for this machine
AssertPathExists=/opt/kafka
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
ExecStop=/opt/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh
```

journalctl show that `java` not found - but java exists via $JAVA_HOME path which is easily found when I start it directly from bash.

I am not an admin user :) so silly mistakes are probably being made here. Please could someone advise? Am I supposed to add it in system.conf file and reload the daemon?

Regards,

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use `Environment` and/or `EnvironmentFile`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes - because I am primarily a Windows user and fully novice compared to you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Systemd, you'll need to explicitly call files with environment variable declarations. For example:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/environment
```

The "-" on the EnvironmentFile= line ensures that no error message is generated if the environment file does not exist. Since many of these files were optional in sysvinit, you should include the "-" when using this directive.

Also, it's worth noting that there are generally three ways to accomplish what you need:

1. As mentioned above, put the variable assignments in a file (like /etc/environment) and reference that file per-unit with `EnvironmentFile=`
2. Reference environment variables right in the individual unit file with `Environment=`
3. Put the variable assignment in the `DefaultEnvironment` variable in /etc/systemd/system.conf or a snippet in /etc/systemd/system.conf.d/some-file.

Check out Fedora's guide on the subject, particularly the [EnrionmentFile section](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Systemd#EnvironmentFiles_and_support_for_.2Fetc.2Fsysconfig_files).

Comment: thanks, funny enough - somehow my bedtime reading didn't cover this - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files. I shall make an effort to cover Fedora's link you've sent me.

Comment: @hagubear: The [`systemd.*(5,7)` man pages](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/) are also useful, if a little dry.

Comment: @hagubear Digital Ocean tutorials are great - very readable and usually authoritative in their subject - but keep in mind they're community-written meaning anyone can write one and therefore they should be supplemented with your own research.
If you found my response answered your question, please mark it as such and you'll be participating in the Superuser community :).